# Cannot use extension command to call async from synchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task

I've discovered an extension method we've been using in our code base to call async methods from synchronous code isn't fully doing what I expected. The code follows the guidelines on MSDN here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2015/july/async-programming-brownfield-async-development

```
public static T AsyncSafeWait<T>(this Task<T> task)
{
    T retVal = default;
    Task.Run(async () => retVal = await task).Wait();
    return retVal;
}
```

This allows simple and intuitive usage:

```
var response = PostAsync(...).AsyncSafeAwait();
```

However, since this is an extension method, the async call is started and thus the current context is captured before handing the `Task` off to the extension method. This causes issues in many synchronous cases, most obvious being on a UI thread where it causes a deadlock. Essentially, the extension method becomes no more useful than `.Result` which is bad practice for the same reasons and more.

My question is: is there any way to wrap up this ugly de-async `Task.Run` code so I don't have to copy-paste `Task.Run(async () => retVal = await TheRealAsyncCall(...)).Wait();` everywhere?

Thank you!

Comment: _"This causes issues in many synchronous cases"_ -- without a _specific_ issue, the question is too broad. But, have you tried simply using `await task.ConfigureAwait(false)` in the `Task.Run()` delegate? If you can improve the question so that it includes a good [mcve] demonstrating _a single specific_ issue to be resolved, that would help make it suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes. Wrap it with async method and make other methods async as well ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> is there any way to wrap up this ugly de-async Task.Run code

No. Any `Task` extension method is run on a single instance of `Task`, and the method must *already* be called by the time the code has a `Task`.

Once your code has a `Task`, it's too late to change how the method is invoked. The best solution is to pass a delegate. Or just delete the `AsyncSafeWait` method completely and then start cleaning up.

Comment: *"Or just delete the `AsyncSafeWait` method completely and then start cleaning up."* - I know you know this Stephen, but I just want to emphasize to the OP that this is really the most ideal way. People keep finding this method and thinking "Microsoft does it, so it must be ok." But it's poison.

Comment: @GabrielLuci: I'm not aware of any `AsyncSafeWait` method by Microsoft that behaves this way; the method is fundamentally broken. The referenced article runs the async code in a `Task.Run`, so a method based on that article *should* be taking a delegate argument, not a `Task`. But yes, I have seen this same problem several times.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't click the link :) I thought it was a reference to [this](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs).